# How can i prevent the error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "72"

Tags: java, numberformatexception

[image: This is the code screenshot]**when i execute the program i get**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "72"
        at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
        at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:957)
        at Convert.main(Convert.java:13)
```

**How can i solve this error**

Comment: Add  the code please.

Comment: probably some additional character (spaces, not visible, not copied, ..) in the string that cannot be converted

Comment: @promod yes i will add

Comment: `valueOf(bb,6)` asks to convert with radix 6. "72" is not valid for radix 6.

Answer (score 1):

At `Convert.java:13` You use `Integer.valueOf(bb, 6)` which means the input string must represent a number in base 6 (radix). *7* is not a valid digit for such a representation, hence the exception. (In base 6, digits must be 0-5 inclusive)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: if i remove integer.valueOf(bb,6) the code runs perfectly